# How to avoid repeating field list in ModelForm and CreateView class?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I'm using `django.forms.ModelForm` and `django.views.generic.CreateView` to create a creation view for my model.

I find that I end up with this code:

forms.py:

```
class ScenarioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = ['scenario_name', 'description',
                  'scenario_file', 'preview']
```

views.py:

```
class ScenarioUpload(generic.CreateView):
    model = Scenario
    fields = ['scenario_name', 'description',
              'scenario_file', 'preview']     
    form_class = ScenarioForm
```

It seems like really bad repetition.  Is there something I'm doing wrong, or some way I can avoid this?

Comment: One ways is defined a class outside say `class OMeta` with class attributes `model` and `fields`. Then (1) defined `class ScenarioForm(forms.ModelForm): class Meta = OMeta` and (2) `class ScenarioUpload(generic.CreateView, OMeta):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tony's answer has the right idea, but the way it actually has to be coded is using "new style" classes, with the mixin listed first in the derived class:

```
class MetaScenario(object):   
    model = Scenario
    fields = ['scenario_name', 'description',
              'scenario_file', 'preview']

class ScenarioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Meta = MetaScenario

class ScenarioUpload(MetaScenario, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = ScenarioForm
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own Meta class:

```
class MetaScenario:
    model = Scenario
    fields = ['scenario_name', 'description',
              'scenario_file', 'preview']

class ScenarioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Meta = MetaScenario

class ScenarioUpload(generic.CreateView, MetaScenario):
    pass
```

Comment: Waw.. Great minds think alike! Lol  -- I suggested same trick in comment.

Comment: But ... I went to implement it and it doesn't work :(   Unfortunately, replacing the contents of the `ScenarioUpload` class with the Meta class parent results in "TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'".  I don't see how anything even "knows" about the difference!